Next-intl reports an error when accessing a SSG subpage without {locale}
I'm using nextjs 14+, app router, next-intl, and it's statically exported
This is the file structure:
src/app/[locale]/page.tsx
src/app/[locale]/about/page.tsx

When I visit http://localhost:3000/, the page will automatically jump to http://localhost:3000/{locale} such as http://localhost:3000/en/
But when I visit a subpage, such as http://localhost:3000/about/, the page will not automatically jump to http://localhost:3000/{locale}/about/ and an error will be reported.
Error: Page "/[locale]/page" is missing param "/about" in "generateStaticParams()", which is required with "output: export" config.

But it is normal for me to directly access http://localhost:3000/{locale}/about/
I used next-intl's https://github.com/amann/next-intl/tree/main/examples/example-app-router to test, and the error was the same
The strange thing is that the homepage can jump automatically. What I want to ask is
Static export is usually solved by automatically jumping to {locale}/ in the end, right? If not, what method is usually used?
How can I make the subpage jump to the page with {locale}/ normally?

Can you try changing your middleware config to this to see if it works?
export const config = {
  
  matcher: [   
    '/((?!api|_next|_vercel|.*\\..*).*)',
    '/([\\w-]+)?/users/(.+)'
  ]
};

You can view more on this page:
https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/routing/middleware#matcher-no-prefix

middleware not support at static export
